# Windows batch - unable to assign a variable within an iterative for loop

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I am using ffprobe to get the codec_name of subtitles in media files. But when I try to get the codec extension it fails. What am I doing wrong?

I have edited this post to address the comments and include the complete batch file

Re: `ns.txt` - this command outputs the stream number of the subtitles:

```batch-file
C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams s -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=language -of csv=p=0 -i "%~dpnx1">ns.txt
```

and the output in the txt file is:

```
2
3
```

Now I need to count the number of lines in this text file which will tell me how many subtitles my media file has:

```batch-file
set "cmd=findstr /R /N "^^" ns.txt | find /C ":""
for /f %%a in ('!cmd!') do set nums=%%a
set /A nums=%nums%-1
```

In this case `nums` = `2` but in `ffprobe` the first subtitle is `s:0`, so I subtract `1` from `nums`

My iterative loop is:

```batch-file
FOR %%i in (1,1,%nums%) DO (
C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffprobe.exe -v quiet -select_streams s:%%i -show_entries stream=%arg% -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -i "%~dpnx1" >sub.txt
set /p codecs=<sub.txt
```

Which puts the codec name in `sub.txt` and I create the variable `codecs` to store this value.

Then I need to determine the appropriate container [extension] for the subtitle - here I changed my code from what I posted earlier:

```batch-file
if !codecs! == mov_text set codecs1=srt
if !codecs! == subrip set codecs1=srt
if !codecs! == ass set codecs1=ass
if !codecs! == webvtt set codecs1=vtt
if !codecs! == ttml set codecs1=ttml
if !codecs! == dvb_subtitle set codecs1=dvbsub
if !codecs! == dvd_subtitle set codecs1=dvdsub
if !codecs! == hdmv_pgs_subtitle setcodecs1=sup
if !codecs! == xsub set codecs1=xsub
```

Then I demux [extract] the subtitle using `ffmpeg`:

```batch-file
c:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg -i "%~dpnx1" -an -vn -c:s "!codecs!" "%~n1_d."!codecs1!"
```

This is working, except I have an extra iteration, my output is:

```
Mediafile: C:\Users\UNOIT\Desktop\Tears of Steel_2sub.mkv
subtile: Tears of Steel_2sub_d.srt
subtile: Tears of Steel_2sub_d.ass
subtile: Tears of Steel_2sub_d.ass
File 'Tears of Steel_2sub_d.ass' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N]
```

And if the media file has only one subtitle, my `ffmpeg` output is:

```
Mediafile: C:\Users\UNOIT\Desktop\_Jan2024-Media\mkv\Tears of Steel_ass.mkv
subtile: Tears of Steel_ass_d.ass
subtile: Tears of Steel_ass_d.ass
File 'Tears of Steel_ass_d.ass' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N]
subtile: Tears of Steel_ass_d.ass
File 'Tears of Steel_ass_d.ass' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N]
```

I can choose not to overwrite the file - but obviously there is a problem with my iterative loop - maybe a subroutine would work

Here is the batch file:

```batch-file
ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set "arg=codec_name"
set "arg1=codec_name"
set "arg2=codec_name"
echo Mediafile: %~dpnx1
C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffprobe -v quiet -loglevel error -select_streams s -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=language -of csv=p=0 -i "%~dpnx1" >ns.txt
set "cmd=findstr /R /N "^^" ns.txt | find /C ":""
for /f %%a in ('!cmd!') do set nums=%%a
set /A nums=%nums%-1
FOR %%i in (0,1,%nums%) DO (
    C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffprobe.exe -v quiet -select_streams s:%%i -show_entries stream=%arg% -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -i "%~dpnx1" >sub%%i.txt
    set /p codecs=<sub%%i.txt
    if !codecs! == mov_text set codecs1=srt
    if !codecs! == subrip set codecs1=srt
    if !codecs! == ass set codecs1=ass
    if !codecs! == webvtt set codecs1=vtt
    if !codecs! == ttml set codecs1=ttml
    if !codecs! == dvb_subtitle set codecs1=dvbsub
    if !codecs! == dvd_subtitle set codecs1=dvdsub
    if !codecs! == hdmv_pgs_subtitle setcodecs1=sup
    if !codecs! == xsub set codecs1=xsub
    echo subtile: %~n1_d.!codecs1!
    c:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg -v quiet -i "%~dpnx1" -an -vn -c:s "!codecs!" "%~n1_d."!codecs1!"
)
```

Comment: I'm struggling to follow the flow. Could you please post all of the relevant code in a single batch file we can all run to reproduce your issue. Please read through [mcve], then [Edit] your question with the required information.

Comment: I added the additional code

Comment: Please just post the full batch file, and preferably for those who cannot, the complete content of `%CD%\ns.txt`, so that we can all copy it, and if needs be, run it with an input file argument of `"%UserProfile%\Desktop\Tears of Steel_2sub.mkv"`.

Comment: Please do not add solutions or answers to the question area. I have removed your previous [Edit].

Comment: BTW, the final line in your batch file has unbalanced doublequotes. I would assume that `"%~n1_d."!codecs1!"` should be `"%~n1_d.!codecs1!"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmm.. This is very confusing to me. I don't understand why you choose the *most complicated way* to perform practically every single step in your code. If I correctly understand what you want, then these are a series of comments about your code:

- In the `ns.txt` file you get "the stream number of the subtitles", but you don't care which these numbers are! You only want to know *how many* subtitles are, so the listing of the contents of ns.txt file (with the lines `2` and `3`) is *totally irrelevant* for the purpose of this code.
- You choose the *most complicated way* to count the number of lines in `ns.txt` file.
- The cause of your problems is that you forgot the `/L` switch in your `FOR %%i in (0,1,%nums%) DO (` command.
- The way to determine the extension for the subtitle can be done in a single line with the aid of an [array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990).

This is my version of your code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set "arg=codec_name"
set "arg1=codec_name"
set "arg2=codec_name"
echo Mediafile: %~dpnx1

rem Define the "codec to container" mapping array
set "extension[mov_text]=srt"
set "extension[subrip]=srt"
set "extension[ass]=ass"
set "extension[webvtt]=vtt"
set "extension[ttml]=ttml"
set "extension[dvb_subtitle]=dvbsub"
set "extension[dvd_subtitle]=dvdsub"
set "extension[hdmv_pgs_subtitle]=sup"
set "extension[xsub]=xsub"

C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffprobe -v quiet -loglevel error -select_streams s -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=language -of csv=p=0 -i "%~dpnx1" >ns.txt
for /F "tokens=3" %%a in ('find /V /C "" ns.txt') do set /A nums=%%a-1
FOR /L %%i in (0,1,%nums%) DO (
   C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffprobe.exe -v quiet -select_streams s:%%i -show_entries stream=%arg% -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -i "%~dpnx1" > sub.txt
   for /F %%a in (sub.txt) do set "codecs=%%a" & set "codecs1=!extension[%%a]!"
   echo subtile: %~n1_d.!codecs1!
   c:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg -v quiet -i "%~dpnx1" -an -vn -c:s "!codecs!" "%~n1_d.!codecs1!"
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to fix this. I'm still learning this stuff. Your   
 code does what I wanted to do - I had to make some small additions to handle mov_test, xsub, dvbsub and dvdsub - have a problem with m2ts files